# php request for images and fill blanks with a default image

Tags: php

I have function that retrieves the images uploaded by each user. The limit per user is 5 images and I want to display a default image to fill the blanks upto 5 if they have less than 5 uploads. How can I achieve this?

```
function display_images() {
    $imgs = get_images();
    $html = '<div class="myImages">';

    foreach($imgs as $img) {
        $html .= '<div class="myImageContainer"><img src="'. $img .'"/></div>';
    }
    $html .= '</div>';
    return $html;
}

function get_images() {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    $args = array(
        'author' => $current_user->ID,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' =>'image',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'orderby' => 'date'
    );
    $query_images = new WP_Query( $args );
    $images = array();
    foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image) {
        $images[]= $image->guid;
    }
    return $images;
}
```

Comment: what did you try? how do you check if there are no 5 images? what is your blank image?

Comment: `if (sizeof($imgs) < 5) { doSomething() }`

Comment: The 5 image limit is done on the upload. How can I modify display_images() to fill the empty images with a defaut one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check for current length of total images:

```
function display_images() {
    $imgs = get_images();
    $html = '<div class="myImages">';

    foreach($imgs as $img) {
        $html .= '<div class="myImageContainer"><img src="'. $img .'"/></div>';
    }
    if (count($imgs)<5) {
        for($i=0; $i<(5-count($imgs)); $i++) {
            $html .= '<div class="myImageContainer"><img src="MY_BLANK_IMAGE_LINK"/></div>';
        }
    }
    $html .= '</div>';
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Working perfectly, just what I needed. Thank you

Comment: Quick question, in the case there are no images uploaded, I don't get the default image in the 5 containers. When there is at least 1 image, it works.

Comment: Could you check is your `$imgs` array empty? Because there shouldn't be problem, it should loop from `0` to `5-0` if `$imgs array` is empty..

Comment: Try to change line `$images[]= $image->guid;` with `if (!empty($images->guid)) { $images[]= $image->guid; } `

Comment: I had some extra code fetching image data that couldn't be returned for the default image and broke the code. Your answers work perfectly, thank you very much